# Don't wait for "Updating service..."

Tags: google-app-engine, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using Bitbucket Pipelines to deploy my project to Google App Engine via `gcloud app deploy` which does a great job accomplishing what I want.

`gcloud app deploy` takes like 6-8 extra minutes for "Updating service..." which is the time taking for them to update their backend infrastructure primarily the Load Balancer.
This is not an issue by itself except that it eats up my monthly Build Time from Bitbucket.
I would rather have the pipeline return as soon it sent off the build commands, and I'll check them myself on Google Cloud Logs server.

The question is: do we have any flag for `gcloud app deploy` to tell him not to wait for the "Updating service..." ?

Comment: I assume if the deployment was unhealthy the `gcloud app deploy` would exit with error and would fail the pipeline. If you manage to not wait for a stable deployment, then your bitbucket deployment would probably always succeed while your gcloud app deployment could fail, so bitbucket would loose track of what was successfully deployed. Not the end of the world, but keep this in mind.

Comment: Correct. And that's what I meant with "and I'll check them myself on Google Cloud Logs server."

Answer (score 1):

[These](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) are all the gcloud app deploy flags. There's no such flag.

To see if there's a possible 'hack' you could use, you could try manually deploying your app yourself using `gcloud app deploy --log-http`.   The `--log-http` flag will produce an output of all http requests made during the deploy. You'll see the endpoints being called, the http method, the headers, payload and the duration for each call. Examining those (especially around the 'updating' bit) might show you something that could potentially be of help.